# How to validate a XMl against a schema XSD with multiple namespace

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, schema

I tried to make a validator of XML in java, having the schema XSD. 
The beginning of my file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dataset xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dwc="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/terms/" xmlns:tcs="http://www.tdwg.org/schemas/tcs/1.01" xmlns:eol="http://www.eol.org/transfer/content/0.3" xmlns:gisin="http://www.gisin.org/gisin/SpeciesStatus" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="AbstractModel.xsd">
<Metadata>...
```

The schema AbstractModel.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:plic="http://www.gbif.es/PliC/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dcelem="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dwc="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/terms/" xmlns:abcd="http://www.tdwg.org/schemas/abcd/2.06" xmlns:tcs="http://www.tdwg.org/schemas/tcs/1.01" xmlns:simple="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/xsd/simpledarwincore/" xmlns:gisin="http://www.gisin.org/gisin/SpeciesStatus" xmlns:eol="http://www.eol.org/transfer/content/0.3" xmlns:eml="eml://ecoinformatics.org/eml-2.1.1" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema" xmlns:ns1="https://github.com/tdwg/dwc/tree/master/xsd">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.tdwg.org/schemas/abcd/2.06" schemaLocation="http://rs.tdwg.org/abcd/2.06/ABCD_2.06.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.tdwg.org/schemas/tcs/1.01" schemaLocation="http://www.tdwg.org/uploads/media/v101.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.gisin.org/gisin/SpeciesStatus" schemaLocation="http://www.gisin.org/GISIN/SpeciesStatus_4_0_0.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/terms/" schemaLocation="tdwg_dwc_extensions.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="eml://ecoinformatics.org/eml-2.1.1" schemaLocation="eml.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.eol.org/transfer/content/0.3" schemaLocation="content_0_3.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" schemaLocation="http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/dcterms.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" schemaLocation="http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/dc.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Dataset">
        <xs:annotation>.......
```

First I followed some examples on internet to make a simple validator class using Java API for XML

```
    public static void validate(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){
    try{
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
    } catch (IOException | SAXException e){
        System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I had read, for read imported XSD is necessary use LSResourceResolver and LSInput, but I don't have an idea how implement theses classes with several XSD's imported. Is possible to do this kind of validation using Java? Is more convenient use some library?

I don't get how I should use the possible answer :[Validate an XML against an XSD in Java / Getting a hold of the schemaLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094662/validate-an-xml-against-an-xsd-in-java-getting-a-hold-of-the-schemalocation)  in my particular problem. For instance, I have a class ResourceResolver that implements LSResourceResolver, but, according to the answer, the constructor of this class need two arguments `public ResourceResolver(URL base, Map<URI, String> nsmap)` I don't know from which class or variable, I should pass these values.

Comment: Is it failing? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate an XML against an XSD in Java / Getting a hold of the schemaLocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094662/validate-an-xml-against-an-xsd-in-java-getting-a-hold-of-the-schemalocation)

Comment: @Xstian. I don't get how I should use that answer in my particular problem. For instance, I have a class ResourceResolver that implements LSResourceResolver, but, according to the answer, the constructor of this class need two parameters `public ResourceResolver(URL base, Map<URI, String> nsmap)`

I don't know from which class or variable, I should pass these values.